# How can I click button every 1 seconds?

Tags: javascript, button, push

I have button declarated:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="top: -1px; position: relative; margin-left: 10px;" onclick="searchProduct()">Refresh / Search</button>
```

What I should write in console to click that button every 1 seconds? I found that code, but I don't know how to use it:

```
setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}, 1000);
```

Comment: make your button have id as "myButtonId" and it works like a charm!

Comment: <button type="button" id="myButtonId" class="btn btn-warning" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button executes the searchProduct() function, so you can directly execute it. No need to click the button

```
setInterval(function() {
  searchProduct();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This could be simplified even further to `setInterval(searchProduct, 1000)` if you wanted (passing the function name instead of creating another function that wraps it). Nice solution though!

Comment: @IneedYOURhelp Great, the : was a accident and needs to be replaced by ; :)

Comment: does this not only execute the `searchProduct()` function once after a second? Does the OP require it to execute every 1 second or only once after a second

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `id` `"myButtonId"` to your html code.

```js
setInterval(function () {
document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();
console.log('click');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="myButtonId" style="top: -1px; position: relative; margin-left: 10px;">
Refresh / Search
</button>
```

Comment: It would be much better to call the code executed by the button instead. Indicated in wkb's answer

Comment: @Uknown  My answer is also an option to address the issue.

Comment: @Damien_Gold Agreed. Your answer is actually more accurate to the question described. I was just pointing out that it would be more ideal to execute the function instead IMHO.

Comment: @Uknown Great. Thank you!